# htaccess The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

and the browser shows error:

**Not Found**

The requested URL /combine.php was not found on this server.

Anybody please help me..thanks.

Comment: Error says all the web server couldn't find `combine.php`. Where exactly it is located?

Comment: combine.php is located in the web root

Comment: Can you directly open: `http://domain.com/combine.php` in browser?

Comment: combine.php can be opened in browser..

Comment: That is very strange then. Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess OR this the only rule?

Comment: I follow the way of this.But I am having problems http://rakaz.nl/code/combine

Comment: where did you place `combine.php` on your server and what is the full URL of a css file?

Answer (score 0):

```
^context/(css|js)/(.*)/?$ /combine.php?type=$1&files=$2
```

for example:

```
    /context/css/testcss/
    /context/js/testjs/
```

will be re-writen respectively as:

```
    /combine.php?type=css&files=testcss
    /combine.php?type=js&files=testjs
```

Make sure that there is no other entry before this that matches this pattern.